# How Do I move these Icons to the respective corners?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am trying to move the fire icon to left and crown to the right. this is what I have written so far...

[image]

```
<SafeAreaView className="flex-1 items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-black">
  <View className="flex-row pt-12">
    <Pressable className="ml-10">
      <MaterialIcons name="local-fire-department" size={24} color="yellow" />
    </Pressable>
    <Pressable className="">
      <FontAwesome5 name="crown" size={22} color="yellow" />
    </Pressable>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `flex-row` defines the direction (row, which is the default and is therefore not needed here). You must specify `flex` to turn the container into a flexbox, separate from the direction.
Then, to fling the two elements to opposing sides (given you only have 2), you can justify with space between:

```
<View className="w-full flex justify-between">
  <Element1 />
  <Element2 />
</View>
```